# Laravel 6 Scan Image and Save in Database

Tags: database, laravel, image, scanning

I'm Using laravel 6 framework in my ecommerce project . I am saving image in my database. 
Now, I want to scan image to my Printer/Scanner and directly input in the website
and save it to database.

How is it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Trigger a Scanner from a Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504231/how-can-i-trigger-a-scanner-from-a-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Hi first i have to say  you should not store image directly in database (in blob data) you can upload image to server folder , link its path (or id, or name or any thing can uniquely identify the image) then create a separate table for it and store that data string data eg:

```
uploaded_images
|id|image_name|alt|updated_at|created_at|
```

and connecting hardware through web browser is a hard thing(camera is possible) unless you have specially created software or browser extension that work like middleware . and it should be installed in user's PC. 
Good luck!