# How to make Java Applet load/charge xml in the same folder at runtime

Tags: java, xml, dll, applet

Hello I'm working on a web application (runs on IE) which is mixed with Applet, XML and DLL files(since app needs to access machine's scanner). The case is somewhat special: When Applet is loaded into browser, it needs to load simultaneously a **scannberLib.jar** and **2 XML files** so as to perform scanning analysis.

There is no problem loading ScannerLib.jar and calling Applet, but 2 XML files are never correctly loaded. **Specially**, we tried the supplied sample application (jar file) and proved scanning analysis only works when 2 XML files are in the same folder of sampleApplication.jar.

The application structure is shown as follows: 
end user----> Web app page ----> page loads Applet (jars & lib)-->Applet calls  init method in scannerLib.jar---->Scanner lib read related DLL files & DLL file (we have no control) read XML file to do scanner analysis...)

My question is how to make java applet "BE AWARE" and"load/charge" other files(xml) at runtime?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: stop working with applets. Most (major) browsers no longer support them, and those who (still) do, will terminate support not long from now

Comment: Hi Stultuske, thanks for your advice. however we have no choice but to develop web apps working on IE (11). Without using applets, how to access to machine material in a web apps? Thank you !

Comment: "machine material"? what do you mean by that? you mean you want to use the users local scanner (device)?

Comment: this might be worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601648/interfacing-with-the-end-users-scanner-from-a-webapp-web-scanner-integration